# PHP to connect to remote MSSQL but getting a list of errors

Tags: php, sql-server

I am using the below code

**Php code**

```
$serverName = "serverName\\sqlexpress, 1433"; //serverName\instanceName, portNumber (default is 1433)
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

**Errors**

> Connection could not be established. Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] =>
>   IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -49 [code] => -49 [2] => This
>   extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server. Access
>   the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for
>   x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 [message] => This
>   extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server. Access
>   the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for
>   x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 ) [1] => Array (
>   [0] => IM002 [SQLSTATE] => IM002 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] =>
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no
>   default driver specified [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]
>   Data source name not found and no default driver specified ) )

Visited the link - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=57163 and downloaded  Microsoft Drivers 5.3 for PHP for SQL Server

I am using wamp32, php-5.6.35 connecting to a MSSQL 2012.

**PHP INFO**
sqlsrv support is enabled

I tried using ASPX(NET) but faced a ton of problems so decided to go with PHP.

Any idea on resolving this would be great.

Comment: if you decided to go with PHP I will recommend you to go with MySql instead of MSSQL. It will make your life easy.

Comment: @azizsagi its for a project that involves MSSQL, client requirements

Comment: are you testing online (hosting provider) or on a localhost?

Comment: @azizsagi on localhost

Comment: For php 5.6 You need to download  driver version 3.2, check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Mate done but same errors

Comment: Verify if your sql server allows remote connections.

Comment: you can check remote connections at

To configure the remote access option
In Object Explorer, right-click a server and select Properties.
Click the Connections node.
Under Remote server connections, select or clear the Allow remote connections to this server check box.

Comment: Uninstall  driver 5.3 ... And check if you have php5.dll / php5ts.dll,  php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll,  php_sqlsrv_56_ts in  your php "ext" folder

Comment: @mate I dont have php5.dll / php5ts.dll but the others, got link to download ?

Comment: @mate does the user have to be a sysadmin to do the connection?

Comment: No, user doesn't need to be sysadmin. Php5 dlls must be in your php folder \xampp\php. Download from originaldll.com/file/php5.dll/30704.html . Last step after copy dll -> restart apache

Comment: @mate done and no change

Comment: try 2 things from windows cmd console. 1. run "php -m "  (Show compiled in modules) and 2. stop and start apache ( not from xampp control). Usually you can see some warning/error when you run it from cmd. AND try to connect to your SQL server from some client like management studio https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I assume you have already installed: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434

Comment: @Mate I installed again just incase... I guess it was the odbc driver issue. Could you please put this as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify:

1. ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for x86:https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434
2. For php 5.6 You need to download driver version 3.2
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017
3. check if you have php5.dll / php5ts.dll, php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll, php_sqlsrv_56_ts in your php "ext" folder
4. Verify if your sql server allows remote connections